# Dynamically update values of a chartjs2.0 chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Most of the answers i found on this topic are for chartjs1.0. So if i have missed something please let me know.

---

So i have a line chart which has two worms plotted.It looks some thing like this[image]

---

My data is populated by a API request and in that response i get a count and a timestamp. I want to achieve something like [this](http://jsbin.com/yitep/5/edit) (Taken from another SO answer). But this implementation uses chartjs1.0.

---

So addData() and removeData() are no more available in chartjs2.0.And i also wanted to update by labels after a particular time.

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Same probleme... Chartjs v2 not really a release...

Answer (score 0):

You can `push()` and `slice()` the arrays of the datasets & labels and then `update()` your chart.

But the motion is not the same and the old `addData()` was way more meaningful.